Why does Sfas Emes start his commentary on Parshat Noach by saying he doesn't know it? Is the translation faulty?
Sfas Emes begins his commentary on Parshat Noach, according to Sefaria, by saying "I do not properly remember." All the other Parshas begin with some variation of "B'H". Why does he say this here? Is it possible the translation of Sefaria is incorrect?


Does he say anything particularly controversial or borderline heretical?

The Sfat Emet isn't originally a written composition, but rather a record of discourses that were delivered orally. So in the year 5631 he just didn't remember perfectly what he had said (understandably, since that was the first year he started recording his discourses in writing).
Here is an example of the Chatam Sofer saying the same thing (last line of his sermon for 7 Av 5560, also interestingly in the first years of recording his sermons).
